# Most combative head-to-head World Championships?

Tags: statistics, records, world-championship

Chess.com keep [tweeting about how combative](https://twitter.com/chesscom/status/1647250929530314753) this match is. 3 out of 5 games so far have been decisive, more than any other match in the last 10 years. Of course, us old timers remember Reykjavik 1972 when 4 out of the first 5 matches ended in wins, albeit not always with both players contributing.

If this match continues at the current pace then it will end with 60% of games being decisive. That will beat the 1972 match which finished with 10 out of 21 games ending in a win for one side or the other - 47.6%.

Of course, Carlsen - Caruana 2018 takes the prize for least combative with all 12 standard time control games ending peacefully.

Which world championship match (including pre-FIDE where results are known and including dual championships in 90's and early 2000's where a match was played) had the highest percentage of decisive games?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of the official matches, the 1889 match between Steinitz and Chigorin appears to be the most combative, with only one draw in the 17th and final game. [World Chess Championship 1889](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_1889)

Several of the prior, unofficial matches, had no draws.

Both match 2, and 6, which was not completed, of the series of matches between La Bourdonnais and McDonnell ended 4-5, with no draws. [La Bourdonnais - McDonnell matches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Bourdonnais_%E2%80%93_McDonnell_chess_matches)

Steinitz also had two earlier matches with no draws, against Anderssen in 1866 (8-6) and Blackburne in 1876 (7-0). [World Chess Championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship#Anderssen,_Morphy_and_Steinitz_(1851%E2%80%931886))